# vue-loader parse error for component decorator

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

I have an issue using vue, typescript, webpack and component decorator.

Here is the error

> ERROR in ./app/modules/popin-ratings-reviews/templates/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts (./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./app/modules/popin-ratings-reviews/templates/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts) 10:0
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (10:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
>   |
>   @Component
>   | export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
>   |     message = 'hello world';
>    @ ./app/modules/popin-ratings-reviews/templates/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts 1:0-130 1:146-149 1:151-278 1:151-278
>    @ ./app/modules/popin-ratings-reviews/templates/HelloWorld.vue
>    @ ./app/modules/popin-ratings-reviews/index.m.ts

It seems that webpack vue-loader can't parse the component decorator syntax.
How can I fix that?

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. Did you find a solution already?

Comment: Yes, I put it in my comment bellow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution

This is the configuration for webpack rules that I use and it is working

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.tsx?$/,
    exclude: [
      /node_modules/
    ],
    use: {
      loader: "ts-loader",
      options: {
        appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    use: {
      loader: "vue-loader"
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more on the babel plugin side / --experimentalDecorators flag where your having the issue.

> Required: ECMAScript stage 1 decorators. If you use Babel,
>   babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy is needed. If you use
>   TypeScript, enable --experimentalDecorators flag.
>
> It does not support the stage 2 decorators yet since mainstream
>   transpilers still transpile to the old decorators.

This seems to be what your looking for.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component